# .Net Session (StateServer mode) not synchronizing if manipulated after request end

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, session, stateserver

I'm getting a bit frustrated with this problem:

I have a web site that manage some files to download, cause these files are very big, and must be organized in folders and then compacted, I build an Ajax structure that do this job in background, and when these files is ready to be downloaded, this job changes the status of an object in the user session (bool isReady = true, simple like that).

To achieve this, when the user clicks "download", a jquery Post is send to an API, and this API starts the "organizer" job and finish the code (main thread, the request scoped one), leaving a background thread doing the magic (it's so beautiful haha).

This "organizer" job is a background thread that receive HttpSessionState (HttpContext.Current.Session) by parameter. It organize and ZIP the files, create a download link and, in the end, change an object in the session using the HttpSessionState that received by param.

This works great when I'm using the session "InProc" mode (I was very happy to deploy this peace of art in production after the tests).

But, my nightmares started when I have deployed the project in production environment, cause we use "StateServer" mode in this environment.
In these environment, the changes is not applied.

What I have noticed, until now, is that in the StateServer, every change I make in the background thread is not "commited" to the session when the changes occurs AFTER the user request ends (the thread that starts the thread).
If i write a thread.join() to wait the thread to finish, the changes made inside the thread is applied.

I'm thinking about use the DB to store these values, but, I will lose some performance :(

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("startDownloadNow")]
        public void StartDownloadNow(DownloadStatusProxy input)
        {
            //some pieces of code...
            ... 

            //add the download request in the user session
            Downloads.Add(data);

            //pass the session as parameter to the thread
            //cause the thread itself don't know the current httpcontext session
            HttpSessionState session = HttpContext.Current.Session;
            Thread thread = new Thread(() => ProccessDownload(data, session));
            thread.Start();
            //here, if I put a thread.join(), the changes inside the thread are applied correctly, but I can't do this, otherwise, it ceases to be ajax
        }

private void ProccessDownload(DownloadStatus currentDownload, HttpSessionState session)
        {
            List<DownloadStatus> listDownload = ((List<DownloadStatus>)session["Downloads"]);

            try
            {
                //just make the magic...
                string downloadUrl = CartClient.CartDownloadNow(currentDownload.idRegion, currentDownload.idUser, currentDownload.idLanguage, currentDownload.listCartAsset.ToArray(), currentDownload.listCartAssetThumb.ToArray());

                listDownload.Find(d => d.hashId == currentDownload.hashId).downloadUrl = downloadUrl;
                listDownload.Find(d => d.hashId == currentDownload.hashId).isReady = true;
                //in this point, if I inspect the current session, the values are applied but, in the next user request, these values are in the previous state... sad... .net bad dog...
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                listDownload.Find(d => d.hashId == currentDownload.hashId).msgError = Utils.GetAllErrors(e);
                LogService.Log(e);
            }
            //this was a desesperated try, I retrieve the object, manipulated and put it back again to the session, but it doesn't works too...
            session["Downloads"] = listDownload;
        }
```

Comment: If you are already using a "StateServer", then I can't see how "I'm thinking about use the DB to store these values, but, I will lose some performance" makes any sense at all. What is a "StateServer" if it's not a database? If this were me, I'd abandon any concept of session state in the webserver. It's a broken concept that doesn't scale. Store everything in the database (without an adapter to persist session state).

Comment: I think StateServer is faster than store data in DB, cause the session works in memory, while DB uses IO. Am I wrong? Or this performance is not so big that I must consider it?